# Positive Width Error?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am using FORTRAN 90 to calculate an expression by building a binary expression tree. I have created a subroutine for the post_order_traversal, and want to format a write statement to output the result without advancing to the next line. This is what I have thus far:

```
Print*, 'The Postfix Expression:' 

Write(101,*) tempPOinter%exp

101 Format (1x, A3, Advance='no') 

                                          1
```

However, when I try to compile, I get an error that reads "Positive width required in format specifier D at (1). If anyone knows what this means or how to fix it, I would be greatly appreciative of your help!
Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

First up, you have put the format line number into the unit location. I think what you want is more like

```
write(*, 101) tempPOinter%exp
```

Secondly, the `advance=no` parameter needs to be placed in the `write` statement, like this:

```
write(*, 101, advance="no") tempPOinter%exp
101 format(1X, A3)
```

You can also put all in one line:

```
write(*, '(1X, A3)', advance='no') tempPOinter%exp
```

For what it's worth: the error comes when it tries to interpret your format statement:

```
101 Format (1x, A3, Advance='no')
```

- `1X` - one space
- `A3` - 3-letter string
- `A` - arbitrary length string
- `d` - double precision float -- need length and how many decimal digits! error!